# android - Lollipop features on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

There is some cool stuff that works only on API 21+. Some of it is pretty easy to imitate on the older APIs, some is included in the Support Library, but about others I have no idea what to do. E.g. so called "Shared objects" when there are some corresponding elements on 2 activities those act as one while activities change.

How is it done on pre-lollipop devices? Or what tricks do good developers use in similar cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared elements are not available pre-lollipop. you can imitate them but its not easy.

you can see this video that replicates it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNF8pXr6whU